# Subsample a matrix python

Tags: python, random

I have a text files that lists pairs, for example

```
10,1
2,7
3,1
10,1
```

That has then been turned into a symmetric matrix, so the (1,10) entry is the number of times the pair (1,10) showed up on the list. I would now like to subsample this matrix. By subsample I mean - I would like to make a matrix that would have been the result of only using a random 30% of the lines in the original text file. So in this example, had I erased 70% of the text file, the (1,10) pair might only show up once instead of twice, and so the (1,10) entry in the  matrix would be 1 instead of 2.

This can be done easily if I actually have the original text file, by just using random.sample to pick out 30% of the lines in the files. But if I only have the matrix, how can I randomly decimate 70% of the data?

Comment: You say that you have a 'symmetric matrix' does that mean you count (10,1) the same as (1,10)?

Comment: Yep - (10,1) and (1,10) are counted as the same. Sorry about the ambiguity

Comment: Okay and 11,11 is the only counted once not twice?

Comment: Yep. All of the necessary data is in the upper triangle...I just populate the lower triangle for convenience with later operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the best way depends on where your data is large:

- Do you have a huge matrix, with mostly small counts in it? or
- Do you have a moderately sized matrix with huge numbers of counts in it?

Here's a solution that will be suited to the second case, though it will also work
OK in the first case.

Basically, the fact that the counts happen to be in a 2D matrix is not so
important: this is basically the problem of sampling from a population that has
been binned. So what we can do is extract the bins directly, and forget about the
matrix for a bit:

```
import numpy as np
import random

# Input counts matrix
mat = np.array([
    [5, 5, 2],
    [1, 1, 3],
    [6, 0, 4]
], dtype=np.int64)

# Build a list of (row,col) pairs, and a list of counts
keys, counts = zip(*[
    ((i,j), mat[i,j])
        for i in range(mat.shape[0])
        for j in range(mat.shape[1])
        if mat[i,j] > 0
])
```

And then sample from those bins, using a cumulative array of counts:

```
# Make the cumulative counts array
counts = np.array(counts, dtype=np.int64)
sum_counts = np.cumsum(counts)

# Decide how many counts to include in the sample
frac_select = 0.30
count_select = int(sum_counts[-1] * frac_select)

# Choose unique counts
ind_select = sorted(random.sample(xrange(sum_counts[-1]), count_select))

# A vector to hold the new counts
out_counts = np.zeros(counts.shape, dtype=np.int64)

# Perform basically the merge step of merge-sort, finding where
# the counts land in the cumulative array
i = 0
j = 0
while i<len(sum_counts) and j<len(ind_select):
    if ind_select[j] < sum_counts[i]:
        j += 1
        out_counts[i] += 1
    else:
        i += 1

# Rebuild the matrix using the `keys` list from before
out_mat = np.zeros(mat.shape, dtype=np.int64)
for i in range(len(out_counts)):
    out_mat[keys[i]] = out_counts[i]
```

Now you will have the sampled matrix in `out_mat`.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately example two and three do not observe correct distribution according to the number of appearances of lines in the original file.

<del>Instead of removing tuples from the original data you could randomly remove counts from your matrix.
So you have to generate random indices and decrease the corresponding count. Be sure to avoid decreasing a zero count and instead generate a new index. Do this until you have decreased the overall amount of counted tuples to 30%.
Basically this could look like this:</del>

```
amount_to_decrease = 0.7 * overall_amount

decreased = 0

while decreased < amount_to_decrease:
    x = random.randint(0, n)
    y = random.randint(0, n)
    if matrix[x][y] > 0:
        matrix[x][y]-=1
        decreased+=1
        if x != y:
            matrix[y][x]-=1
```

<del>This should work well if your matrix is well populated.
If it's not</del>  you might want to recreate a list of tuples from the matrix and then choose a random subset from that. After this recreate your matrix from the remaining tuples:

```
tuples = []
for y in range(n):
    for x in range(y+1):
        for _ in range(matrix[x][y])
            tuples.append((x,y))
remaining = random.sample(tuples, int(overall_amount*0.7) )
```

<del>Or you can do a combination where you do a first pass to find all indices that are not zero and then sample these to decrease the counts:</del>

```
valid_indices = []
for y in range(n):
    for x in range(y+1):
        valid_indices.append((x,y))

amount_to_decrease = 0.7 * overall_amount
decreased = 0
while decreased < amount_to_decrease:
    x,y = random.choice(valid_indices)
    matrix[x][y]-=1
    if x != y:
        matrix[y][x]-=1
    if matrix[y][x] == 0:
        valid_indices.remove((x,y))
```

There is another approach that would use the right possibilities but might not give you an exact reduction. The idea is to set a probability for keeping a line/count. This could be 0.3 if you are aiming for a reduction to 30%. Then you can go over the matrix and check for every count if it should be kept or not.

```
keep_chance = 0.3
for y in range(n):
    for x in range(y+1):
        for _ in range(matrix[x][y])
            if random.random() > keep_chance:
                matrix[x][y] -= 1
                if x != y:
                    matrix[y][x]-=1
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I guess I should have added, the number of rows in the original text file is actually quite large, so it would be great to this via slicing instead of a for loop. The matrix itself is also large - N = 20,000. But it also sparse (most pairs don't appear in the list), so the condition if matrix[x][y] > 0 will usually be false. Might make sense to convert to sparse matrix notation and randomly sample and subtract one from its entries? In this case I still have a big for loop, but at least I can avoid the check for 0 entries...

Comment: I added another approach that does something like this. Somehow you have to find out which values are not zero. After that you can sample only the valid indices.

Comment: Great, will try out these ideas and see which one can get the job done in a reasonable amount of time. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just made another edit to the last example that might reduce the traversal time, since it only looks at one half of the matrix instead of all of it

Comment: You will want to be a little careful how the points are weighted. The second option weights by counts, the first and third weights all locations equally. Not sure which is what you want.

Comment: Okay I guess it should all be weighted by count. But that does make the 'improvements' of the third one void, since you again have to account for the count.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the couples 1,10 and 10,1 are different, so that mat[1][10] is not necessarily the same as mat[10][1] (if not, read below the line)

First compute the sum of all the values in the matrix.

Let this sum be **S**. This counts the number of rows in the file.

Let **x** and **y** the dimensions of the matrix.

Now loop for **n** from 0 to [70% of S]:

- pick a random integer between 1 and x. let this be **j**
- pick a random integer between 1 and y. let this be **k**
- if mat[j][k] > 0, decrease mat[j][k] and do n++

Since you increase a single value in the matrix for each row in your file, decreasing randomly a positive value in the matrix is the same as decimating the rows in the file.

---

If 10,1 is the same of 1,10 you don't need half of the matrix, so you can change the algorithm like this:

Loop for **n** from 0 to [70% of S]:

- pick a random integer between 1 and x. Let this be **j**
- pick a random integer between 1 and k. Let this be **k**
- if mat[j][k] > 0, decrease mat[j][k] and do n++